# How to run Parametrized JUnit Test in JMeter

Tags: junit, jmeter, load-testing

I've created parametrized JUnit test (parametrized the text for username field) and the test running successfully in Eclipse. Now, I'd like to use the same Junit test in JMeter for Load testing.

When I'm trying to run the test using JMeter in username field the following text is typed instead of the actual parameterized value:

**org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler**

Culd anyone please let me know how to use parametrized JUnit tests in Jmeter?