# Jmeter: Using jmeter Junit Request with variables

Tags: junit, jmeter

As I said in the question, is it possible to pass jmeter variables (passed through -J) into a `JUnit Request` in order that it can be used internally to the junit test?

It sounds feasible as [the Apache Junit Request docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) indicate that:

> ... JMeter currently runs the test methods directly, rather than
>   leaving it to JUnit. ...

This would indicate that jmeter could control passing parameters but I've found no supporting documentation and there's no obvious mechanism through the JUnit Request sampler config.

**Background**

I was hoping to use `CSV Data Set Config` to load a user pool (as in [Victor Klepikovskiy excellent top tips](http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/tip-10-how-to-add-authorization-to-test.html)) and have a randomly obtained user provided to my unit-tests (for use across the thread/ loop). I've found an alternative way of doing what I want (but use my own user pool accessed from within the junit tests). I know you could manage the login through  `Http Request` too (as above) but we amanage the rest-service calls internally to junit so that they can be run as junit tests as well. I was interested in being as non-intrusive as possible.

A second reason for doing so might be to have a single junit test method but have it parameterised to suit the scenario.

**Addendum**

For what it's worth, I'm happy with my current alternative approach but still interested in how you might be able to do this for future reference. I'm fairly new to jmeter but expect to see a fair bit more of it. Was also thinking of looking at the pre-processors but not sure how these could interface with the Junit Request.

Comment: Though I did diligently search before asking the question, it seems this question also already exists as [How to run Parametrized JUnit Test in JMeter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10979212/758831) although there are currently no responses. Put this comment in to link them

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do exactly what you are doing (although, never specifically used -J). 
The short answer is I have still not found a way to make it work to pass variables into a JUnit Request. I believe it is not currently supported.

At the time, the only way I saw of doing this was passing a parameter (e.g., **${__threadNum}** or even from **CSV Data Set Config**) into the *Constructor String Label* and writing my constructor appropriately. However, I only got the string literal "**${__threadNum}**". I contacted support and they mentioned to me that this will not work. I forget exactly what they said and cannot find the email. But the main idea was that a JUnit Request is instantiated or created before the parameter in the *Conostructor String Label* is parsed. So that is why it will not work.

I am currently using the same alternative you are by having my test read credentials from a file.

Comment: girlytech59, is it against the rules to mention what solution I am using with JMeter?

Comment: thanks for your feedback - and concurring that there is no parameterisation mechanism with `JUnitRequest`. I thought of using the thread label (Constructor parameter) but it felt like too much of a misuse and that run stats reporting would be affected so I veered away. I read your unedited response too - thanks for the extra info on BlazeMeter.

Comment: Not investigated this further but found something of interest. It may be possible to manage it as a plain `JavaRequest`, taking default parameters for the username and password (which could be parameterised and made to work with the CSVDataSetconfig). See this article: [Apache Jmeter Load-test Whatever You Like](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/apache-jmeter-load-test-whatever-you.html)

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for sharing. I will have to try this out sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and it all works. what needs to be done is:
Source: blazemeter.com how-use-junit-jmeter

1) add the following jar files in the project libraries:

..\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_core.jar

..\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_junit.jar

2) in the class, add the reference to the sampler:

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler;

3) Add the code in the @Test tag to handle variables:
[Click to see Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQvZD.png)

4) Define variables in JMeter (both in user define variables and CSV)

[Click to see JMeter Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qq8d.png)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Efraim, thanks for the response. Not sure this addresses the issue I was looking to fix. I want to be able to read data from `CSV Data Set Config` and pass it to a `JunitSampler` - so that a JUnit thread can be configured to run with that data. For instance, so  JunitSampler` can take user login credentials and run its test as that user. The part - passing the data to the `JUnitSampler` seemed to be where the issue was. I'm not playing with Jmeter at the mo so it may have changed though. Thanks.

Comment: got you. you can do what you want by defining the variable name in the csv config and referencing it with the same name in the junit code. it has worked for me

Comment: That would be great... Accessing it from within the junit test? Could you include a snippet example of your junit code referencing the CSV variable please? I'm not in a position to test this (it's an old question - and lucky me I'm working with LoadRunner) but if anyone independently verified it, I would accept your answer+upvote. Thanks.

Comment: the links in the post show the code in junit and the config in jmeter